# BackendException: Could not initialize backend: No module named gi.repository

Tags: backup

I have installed Ubuntu and have scheduled backup. Every time I log in to  my account, I see a back up error as

```
BackendException: Could not initialize backend: No module named gi.repository.
```

Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
sudo apt install python-gi
```

maybe you need this too:

```
sudo apt install duplicity
```

Comment: depending on where the store location is you need to create and/or set file permissions as well of that target store location

Comment: `sudo apt-get install python-gi` should help, see [here](https://answers.launchpad.net/deja-dup/+question/276745).